# How to make folders invisible to certain users

Tags: samba, shared-folders, acl

I use a Samba share pointing to a directory with all my files. As several users access the same share and I don't want every user accessing every folder, I use ACL to restrict them. Is there any way to also hide certain folders to certain users, while showing those folders to other users?